# Assign menu programmatically upon saving node

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I'm using Superfish module for my menu. I have product parent menu where I need to display the 3 categories as sub-menu. Those 3 categories has been added to the menu with the help of Taxonomy menu module.

I would like to assign a menu automatically based from the nodes category.

For example:-

"Node 1" has "Category 1" term, then the node menu will be assigned to "Category 1". Something like below:-

```
-Product
 --Category 1
    ---Node 1
    ---Node 2
  --Category 2
    ---Node 3
    ---Node 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function YOUR_MODUEL_node_insert($node){
  create_node_menu($node, 'insert');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_update().
 */
function YOUR_MODUEL_node_update($node){
  create_node_menu($node, 'update');
}

function create_node_menu($node, $action_type){
  if($node->type == 'YOUR_NODE_TYPE'){
    $category = $node->field_category[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $menu_name = '';
    switch($category){
      case "A":
        $menu_name = 'menu-menu-a';
        break;
      case "B":
        $menu_name = 'menu-menu-b';
        break;
      case "C":
        $menu_name = 'menu-menu-c';
        break;
    }
    if(!empty($menu_name)){
      $item = array(
        'menu_name' => $menu_name,
        'link_title' => $node->title,
        'link_path' => 'node/'. $node->nid,
      );
// update already created menu link
      if($action_type == 'update'){
        $mlid = db_select('menu_links' , 'ml')
            ->condition('ml.link_path', 'node/'.$node->nid)
            ->condition('ml.menu_name', $menu_name)
            ->fields('ml' , array('mlid'))
            ->execute()
            ->fetchField();
        $item['mlid'] = $mlid;
      }
      $mlid = menu_link_save($item);
      menu_cache_clear_all();
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I'm just quite not sure what to put in $menu_name = 'menu-menu-a'; Is it that the category menu id? Like $menu_name = 'menu-menu:' + $id; ???

Comment: $menu_name will be the machine name of menu. For example, if your menu name is "Blog" then menu name here will be "menu-blog" You can see it by editing your menu.